Streamlit metric alignment with delta
In Streamlit, I have a main stats column and a comparison column. The comparison column's metric component has a delta while the main one's does not. This delta misaligns all the following components in the comparison column. How do I make the delta and non-delta metrics occupy the same vertical space so that elements following the metric aren't misaligned?
Problem (note how horizontal lines are misaligned):
import streamlit as st

c1, c2, c3 = st.columns(3)
with c1:
    st.metric("Main", 1, delta=None, delta_color="normal")
    st.write("------------------------")
with c2:
    st.metric("Compare", 1, delta=1, delta_color="normal")
    st.write("------------------------")
with c3:
    st.metric("asdf", 1, delta=None, delta_color="normal")
    st.write("------------------------")



You can use custom CSS to accomplish what you want:
import streamlit as st

css = """
<style>
div[data-testid="stMetric"] {
    min-height: 100px;
}
</style>
"""
st.markdown(css, unsafe_allow_html=True)

c1, c2, c3 = st.columns(3)

with c1:
    st.metric("Main", 1, delta=None, delta_color="normal")
    st.markdown("---")
with c2:
    st.metric("Compare", 1, delta=1, delta_color="normal")
    st.markdown("---")
with c3:
    st.metric("asdf", 1, delta=None, delta_color="normal")
    st.markdown("---")

It gives:

I set 100px for the height but you can decrease the value if you prefer a more squeezed version for instance.

You can use ALT+255. It will create a blank space and it will work the way you want. For example:
st.metric('Observed - Average', f"{avg_his_gn:,.2f} MWh", delta = "ALT+255") 

